# What are the operations to allocate memory in Common Lisp? (in the minimal version of the language implementation)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I thought that the only operation was *cons*, but it seems there are others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any operation which creates a new object will necessarily allocate some kind of resource for it.  It's almost impossible to enumerate such things, and some of them don't really have names.  For instance

```
(defun c (a)
  (lambda (b)
    (+ b a)))
```

May allocate memory each time it is called and certainly sometimes must do so, but there probably is nothing preventing `(eq (c 1) (c 1))` from being true either.

```
(defun d ()
  (lambda (b)
    b))
```

Does not ever need to allocate memory but may do so (in the implementation I tried it on it does so in interpreted code, but does not do so in compiled code).

```
(defun e (a)
  (lambda (b)
    (incf a b))
```

must always allocate (so `(eq (e 1) (e 1))` cannot be true).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. But from a specific "memory perspective", _cons_ should be the only operation that actively allocates memory. What I mean is that _cons_ does nothing else except allocating the memory for the cons-cell am I right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'from a specific "memory perspective"'.  That seems like the wrong way of thinking about CL to me.

Comment: Common Lisp does not have only cons cells. A number is not a cons cell, but may also need to be allocated somewhere.

Comment: @tfb I used that expression because the question I asked was from my teacher, and to me it sounds like: "Tell me all the operations that only allocate memory", like... Without doing anything else. I am pretty confused too, so I tried to explain myself as well as possible 

Comment: @RainerJoswig This is interesting... I thought that memory in Common Lisp was organized in cons cells. For example a number would be stored in a cons cell where the _CAR_ is the number and the _CDR_ is **nil**

Comment: @Lorenzo: what made you think that? Then `3` would be the same as `(3)`. That makes no sense.

Comment: @RainerJoswig My professor at university told me that LISP means "LISt Processing" and that all the programs written in CL can be seen as "giant lists". That is why I thought that _cons_ was the mother of everything in CL.

Comment: Lorenzo: now you have a ship with containers. The ship is a giant piece of steel, containing containers, those also made of steel. Inside these containers are oranges. Are the oranges themselves containers made of steel?

Comment: @Lorenzo: I'm afraid your professor told you something that's not true.  Very ancient Lisps had fewer ways of allocating memory and fewer data types (but even *very* ancient ones had more than `CONS`), but it is very definitely not the case that everything in CL is a cons.

Answer (score 4):

A Lisp system must somehow provide memory allocation and management for all the object kinds that it provides. The `cons` function is a dedicated allocator/constructor only for cons cells, and objects made of one or more cons cells. Common Lisps also feature all kinds of objects that are usually not made of cons cells.

The Common Lisp standard language doesn't expose any low-level memory allocation. Objects of all kinds come into being in three ways: construction by a dedicated function, like `make-symbol`; construction from syntax by the reader, and by transformation of existing values to make new values. For instance  `(subseq "abcd" 1 3)` yields `"bc"`, which is a newly allocated string object, whose `bc` data is likely new allocated memory also.

A Common Lisp implementor has to take stock of all the various kinds of objects that are to be provided, choose representations for them and implement all those functions somehow, with some underlying memory management strategies. There can be more than one memory management system. Some objects can be made of pieces that come from different allocators. E.g. a string object could come from a similar allocator to the one for conses, taking advantage of all such objects being equal sized, but the raw character data of the string (referenced by the string object) could come from a different allocator geared toward strings.